Proving negativeness of function involving $-\log t$
I have been trying to solve the following function is non-increasing with respect $\theta$
\begin{equation}
h(t,\beta) = \frac{1-t-\frac{\beta(-\log t)^{\theta}}{\theta(-\log \beta)^{\theta -1}}}{1-\beta-\frac{\beta}{\theta}(-\log \beta)}
\end{equation}
where $0<\beta<t<1$ and $\theta>2$.
However, differentiation with respect $\theta$ seems to get nowhere.
I have also tried a direct approach like consider $\theta_1 < \theta_2$, then I should prove that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1-t-\frac{\beta(-\log t)^{\theta_2}}{\theta_2 (-\log \beta)^{\theta_2 -1}}}{1-\beta-\frac{\beta}{\theta_2}(-\log \beta)} \leq \frac{1-t-\frac{\beta(-\log t)^{\theta_1}}{\theta_1(-\log \beta)^{\theta_1 -1}}}{1-\beta-\frac{\beta}{\theta_1}(-\log \beta)}
\end{equation}
or equivalently, show that the function
\begin{equation}
f(t) = \left( 1-t-\frac{\beta(-\log t)^{\theta_2}}{\theta_2 (-\log \beta)^{\theta_2 -1}}\right) \left( 1-\beta-\frac{\beta}{\theta_1}(-\log \beta)\right) - \left( 1-t-\frac{\beta(-\log t)^{\theta_1}}{\theta_1 (-\log \beta)^{\theta_1 -1}}\right) \left( 1-\beta-\frac{\beta}{\theta_2}(-\log \beta)\right)
\end{equation}
is non-positive for all $t \in (\beta,1)$. Note that $f(\beta)=f(1)=0$, so I tried to plot this function for some values and it is negative, and had the idea to show that $f^{\prime}(\beta)$ is negative and $f^{\prime}(1)$ is positive, and that $f^{\prime \prime}(t)>0$, but results that $f^{\prime}(\beta)=0$ and for the concavity I had
\begin{align}
f''(t) = \frac{\beta \log \beta}{t^2 \theta_1 \theta_2 (\log t)^2} \Bigg[ \,
& - \theta_1 \left( -\log \beta \right)^{-\theta_1} \left( \theta_2 - \beta \theta_2 + \beta \log \beta \right)
\left( \theta_1 - 1 - \log t \right) \left( -\log t \right)^{\theta_1} \nonumber \\
& + \theta_2 \left( -\log \beta \right)^{-\theta_2} \left( \theta_1 - \beta \theta_1 + \beta \log \beta \right)
\left( \theta_2 - 1 - \log t \right) \left( -\log t \right)^{\theta_2}
\, \Bigg]
\end{align}
that seems not possible to determine its sign. Is anything I am missing.
I'd appreciate any hint you could give me.
Best

Assuming that $\log$ here stands for $\ln$, write $a,b,t$ in place of $-\ln t,-\ln\beta,\theta$, respectively, so that $a>0,b>0,t>2$.
The task is to show that
\begin{equation}
    H(t):=H(t;a,b):=\frac{1-e^{-a}-\dfrac{a^t b^{1-t} e^{-b}}{t}}{1-e^{-b}-\dfrac{b
   e^{-b}}{t}}
\end{equation}
is decreasing (in $t>2$ for $a,b>0$).
It is enough to show that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    H_1(t)&:=H_1(t;a,b):=H'(t)\Big/ 
    \frac{a^t b^{1-t} e^{-a}}{(b+t-e^b t)^2} \\ 
&=
    e^a \Big(e^b-1-((e^b-1) t-b) \ln\frac{a}{b}\Big)-(e^a-1) e^b
   \Big(\frac{b}{a}\Big)^t<0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
(here throughout $a>0,b>0,t>2$).
To do this, note first that
\begin{equation}
    H''_1(t)=-\Big(\frac{b}{a}\Big)^t e^b(e^a-1)\ln^2\frac ba\le0,
\end{equation}
so that $H_1(t)$ is concave in $t$.
Next,
\begin{equation}
    H'_1(2)=(e^a-1)(e^b-1)(g(b)-g(a))\ln\frac{a}{b},
\end{equation}
where $g(a):=\dfrac{a^2 e^a}{e^a-1}$, so that $g'(a)=\dfrac{a e^a \left(2 (e^a-1)-a\right)}{\left(e^a-1\right)^2}>0$. So, $g$ is increasing and hence $H'_1(2)\le0$.
It remains to show that $H_1(2)\le0$. Letting
\begin{equation}
    H_{12}(b):=H_{12}(a,b):=\frac{H_1(2)}{e^a(2(e^b-1)-b)}
\end{equation}
(which is of the same sign as $H_1(2)$), we have
\begin{equation}
    H'_{12}(b)\frac{a^2 b\, (2(e^b-1)-b)^2 e^a}{(e^a-1)(e^b-1)} \\ 
    =(g(a)-g(b))((4 (e^b-1)-b (3 + b) ),
\end{equation}
which is of the same sign as $g(a)-g(b)$ and hence of the same sign as $a-b$. So, $H_{12}(b)$ is increasing in $b\in(0,a]$ and decreasing in $b\in[a,\infty)$. So, $H_{12}(b)\le H_{12}(a)=0$. So, $H_1(2)\le0$. $\quad\Box$

Thank you so much for your assistance. The idea of changing variables was very neat. However, there is something I don't understand. It says that you want to show that $H(t)$ is increasing in $t$, don't you mean decreasing? Again, thank you.

@MSquared : Of course, decreasing, and that is what was proved. This is now fixed.

Thank you so much.
